# Find the solution of the recurrence relation (fibonacci)

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

---

Find the solution of the recurrence relation $f_n = f_{n-1} + f_{n-2}$ with $f_0 = f_1 = 1$

I had someone show me how to solve/prove this using the linear difference equation, but I had never been exposed to such equation (I think that's more advance than what I'm currently studying), how would I had been able to solve this (without knowing that equation)? Is there a more straight forward solution to this using mathematical induction instead? I was first gonna do $n = 2$, and while that simply shows $f_2 = 2$, that doesn't confirm any base cases (from what I understand anyway) and I can't use $n = 1$ or $n = 0$ (from what I have tried). So I'm assuming do I need some kind of closed form equation on the left hand side or? I'm barely starting to learn proofs, any insight would be grateful. Thanks.

Comment: What's your background, any linear algebra?

Comment: no linear algebra knowledge, yet anyway. Just calculus so far.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose I tell you that a sequence ${a_0,a_1,...}$ is defined recursively by:

$$a_{n+1}=3a_{n}$$

Then you notice from this that to get to the next number in the sequence, you multiply by $3$. And by playing around with the sequence, you notice that it's solution is basically:

$$a_n=a_0(3)^n$$

Now suppose I  give you:

$$f_{n+2}-f_{n+1}-f_n=0$$

And ask you to solve it.

A good guess to the solution would be something of the form $f_n=c_1r^n$ as we seen from the first example.
Here $c_1$ and $r$ are constants. plugging this into the equation above and dividing by $c_1$ on both sides, we get:

$$r^{n+2}-r^{n+1}-r^n=0$$

Dividing by $r^n$ on both sides we get (note that the solution $r=0$ is lost, but it is not that interesting):

$$r^2-r-1=0$$

$$r=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2},\\\  \frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}$$

Any choice of $r$ above will satisfy the equation. However if we combine the two possible values of $r$, we get yet another solution:

$$a_n=c_1(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n+c_2(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n$$

In which case now ,given the initial values of your sequence:

$$f_0=1$$

$$f_1=1$$

You may solve for the constants in the equation, and check to make sure that it satisfies all conditions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint to the hint: As $$f_{n+2} - f_{n+1} - f_n = 0$$, the immediate quadratic equation is $$r^2 - r - 1 = 0$$.
If you solve that through
$$ x = \frac {-b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} $$
you will obtain two values: $r_1$ and $r_2$.

As @Bernard says, you have to calculate $\lambda $ and $\mu $ in $f (n) = \lambda r_1^n+\mu r_2^n$, expression that is true for certain lambda and mu for all $n \geq 0$.

For that, try to relate $f (0)$ and $f (1) $ with $\lambda $ and $\mu $ and you will obtain a system with 2 equations and 2 variables.

Solve it and you will obtain lamda and mu. Substitute back and you will obtain what you were looking for:

$$f (n) =\lambda r_1^n+\mu r_2^n$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Search solutions to the recurrence relation in the form $r^n$ (i.e. geometric sequences) for a suitable $r$. This will lead you to a quadratic equation for $r$, with two solutions $r_1$ and $r_2$..

Then check any linear combination of solutions is a solution. Hence for any $\lambda, \mu$,  $\lambda r_1^n+\mu r_2^n$ is a solution.

Finally, check there is only one of these solutions that satisfy the initial conditions.

Comment: I think linear combination of solutions is related to linear algebra, I'm not quite there yet, unfortunately. I've only taken calculus.

Comment: One does not have to know linear algebra to understand linear combinations, as you've seen them with vectors in high school…